# Duplication with nested null checks

Tags: java, null

How can I improve this code with nested null check statements?

```
public class AcrCategoryService extends BaseActionService<AcrCategoryModel> {

    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    public Map getCategoryList(String categoryCd, String categoryNm, String rgstTrgt) throws Exception{        
        Map model = new HashMap();
        fileService.setIsGetFile(true);

        try {            

            List<AcrCategoryModel> cateData = acrCategoryDao.getCategoryList(categoryCd, categoryNm, rgstTrgt);

            for(AcrCategoryModel acr : cateData)
            {
                if(acr.getAttrNo() == null)
                {
                    System.out.println("------------------------getAttrNo is null");
                } else
                {
                    System.out.println("======getAttrNo===================>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"+acr.getAttrNo());
                    FileModel file = (FileModel)fileService.get(acr.getAttrNo()).get("fileList");
                    acr.setListImg("<img src='"+file.getFilebyte()+"' height='25' width=100>");
                }
            }
            model.put("categoryList", cateData);    

        } catch(Exception e) {
            throw new Exception(e);
        }

        return model;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    public Map get(String categoryId, Integer attrNo) throws Exception{
        Map model = new HashMap();
        fileService.setIsGetFile(true);
        try {
            AcrCategoryModel categoryInfo = (AcrCategoryModel)acrCategoryDao.get(categoryId);
            model.put("categoryInfo", categoryInfo);

            List<AcrCategoryModel> subCateList = acrCategoryDao.getSubCate(categoryId);
            model.put("subCateList", subCateList);

            List<AcrCategoryModel> accAreaList = acrCategoryDao.getAccArea(categoryId);
            model.put("accAreaList", accAreaList);

            if(categoryInfo.getAttrNo() == null)
            {
            } else
            {
                model.put("fileList", fileService.getList(categoryId, categoryInfo.getAttrNo()).get("fileList"));
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }

        return model;
    }
    }

    public class AcrColorService extends BaseActionService<AcrColorModel> {

    @Autowired
    private AcrColorDao acrColorDao;
    @Autowired
    private FileService fileService;

    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    public Map getColorList(String colorCd, String colorNm) throws Exception{        
        Map model = new HashMap();
        fileService.setIsGetFile(true);

        try {            

            List<AcrColorModel> colorData = acrColorDao.getColorList(colorCd, colorNm);

            for(AcrColorModel acr : colorData)
            {
                if(acr.getAttrNo() == null)
                {
                    System.out.println("------------------------getAttrNo is null");
                } else
                {
                    System.out.println("======getAttrNo===================>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"+acr.getAttrNo());
                    FileModel file = (FileModel)fileService.get(acr.getAttrNo()).get("fileList");
                    acr.setListImg("<img src='"+file.getFilebyte()+"' height='15' width=200>");
                }
            }
            model.put("colorList", colorData);    

        } catch(Exception e) {
            throw new Exception(e);
        }

        return model;
    }

    public void deleteTrgStatusAction(AcrColorModel colorModel) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        for (Map<String,String> colorInfo : colorModel.getColorList()) {
            if(colorInfo.get("attrNo") != null && !colorInfo.get("attrNo").equals(""))
            {
                FileModel fileModel = new FileModel();
                fileModel.setFileSeq(colorInfo.get("colorId").toString());
                fileModel.setAttrNo(Integer.parseInt(colorInfo.get("attrNo")));
                fileService.remove(fileModel);
            }

            acrColorDao.remove(colorInfo);
        }
    }


    public void updateTrgStatusAction(AcrColorModel colorModel, Map model) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(colorModel.getImgPath()!=null && colorModel.getImgPath().getSize()>0)
        {
            if(colorModel.getAttrNo() != null)
            {
                FileModel fileModel = new FileModel();                    
                fileModel.setFileSeq(colorModel.getColorId().toString());
                fileModel.setAttrNo(colorModel.getAttrNo());
                fileService.remove(fileModel);
            }

            int attrNo = 0;
            attrNo = fileService.fileWrite(Constants.ServiceId.ACR_COLOR, colorModel.getColorId().toString(), colorModel.getImgPath());

            if(attrNo != 0)
                colorModel.setAttrNo(attrNo);
        }

        acrColorDao.modify(colorModel);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    public void createTrgStatusAction(AcrColorModel colorModel, Map model) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        acrColorDao.add(colorModel);
        colorModel.setTrStatus(Constants.TrStatus.UPDATE);

        int attrNo = 0;
        if(colorModel.getImgPath()!=null && colorModel.getImgPath().getSize()>0)
            attrNo = fileService.fileWrite(Constants.ServiceId.ACR_COLOR, colorModel.getColorId().toString(), colorModel.getImgPath());

        if(attrNo != 0)
        {
            colorModel.setAttrNo(attrNo);
            acrColorDao.modify(colorModel);
        }

        model.put("colorInfo", colorModel);
    }
    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    public Map get(String colorId) throws Exception{
        Map model = new HashMap();
        fileService.setIsGetFile(true);
        try {
            AcrColorModel acrColorInfo = (AcrColorModel)acrColorDao.get(colorId);
            model.put("colorInfo", acrColorInfo);

            if(acrColorInfo.getAttrNo() == null)
            {

            } else
            {
                model.put("fileList", fileService.getList(colorId, acrColorInfo.getAttrNo()).get("fileList"));
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }

        return model;
    }
}
```

I hate nested null check among different classes in this code.  Can I make a method and move it up to a super class?

Answer (score 13):

Use rawtypes is even worse than null check!

Your

```
Map model = new HashMap();
```

should be

```
Map<String, List<AcrCategoryModel>>  model = new HashMap<String, List<AcrCategoryModel>>();
```

or if you use Java >= 7

```
Map<String, List<AcrCategoryModel>>  model = new HashMap<>();
```

Do the same for others. With this you remove the useless casting!

---

```
} catch(Exception e) {
    throw new Exception(e);
}

} catch (Exception e) {
    throw e;
}
```

2 problems here:

1. You catch the exception but then rethrow the same without a message/or similar how can this be helpful? You should throw another exception which is more specific in your case or just remove the catch.
2. Don't catch `Exception`! If it's `IOException` catch it. Then if you want, you can throw another if you think exists another exception which helps the programmer to understand better the error.

---

```
if(categoryInfo.getAttrNo() == null)
{
} 
else
{
   model.put("fileList", fileService.getList(categoryId, categoryInfo.getAttrNo()).get("fileList"));
}
```

If you need to do something if it's null, do something or just ignore it. Your code can be just:

```
if(categoryInfo.getAttrNo() != null)
{
   model.put("fileList", fileService.getList(categoryId, categoryInfo.getAttrNo()).get("fileList"));
}
```

And fix your indentation!

```
return model;
}
}
```

Note the two `}}` this let me think: "he closed two times the method?" then i noticed it's the method and class close. With indentation the code will be clear for you and others.

```
public Map get(String categoryId, Integer attrNo)
```

Avoid use of boxed natives types this could create problems if you don't be careful.

---

```
if(colorInfo.get("attrNo") != null && !colorInfo.get("attrNo").equals(""))
```

What about cache `.get("attrNo")` value?

```
String attrNo = colorInfo.get("attrNo");
if(attrNo  != null && !attrNo.equals(""))
```

I would like to talk about **how to avoid null** checks at the end of the answer, but i give an hint here:

You can avoid the null check if inverting your `.equals` condition.

```
"".equals(attrNo)
```

It's legal, so if `attrNo` is null it will return false.

Ah, if you need to check if the string is empty use `.isEmpty()` or `.length()`!

(p.s since you cache `attrNo` you will use it inside `fileModel.setAttrNo(Integer.parseInt(colorInfo.get("attrNo")));` too)

---

```
int attrNo = 0;
attrNo = fileService.fileWrite(Constants.ServiceId.ACR_COLOR, colorModel.getColorId().toString(), colorModel.getImgPath());
```

What about

```
int attrNo = fileService.fileWrite(Constants.ServiceId.ACR_COLOR, colorModel.getColorId().toString(), colorModel.getImgPath());
```

?

```
if(attrNo != 0)
        colorModel.setAttrNo(attrNo);
```

Add the `{ }` you code will be more clear and in future you can edit your code without think two times about it.

```
if(attrNo != 0) {
   colorModel.setAttrNo(attrNo);
}
```

---

The same of above here

```
    if(colorModel.getImgPath()!=null && colorModel.getImgPath().getSize()>0)
       attrNo = fileService.fileWrite(Constants.ServiceId.ACR_COLOR, colorModel.getColorId().toString(), colorModel.getImgPath());
```

---

It should be all, now how to avoid null checks?

It depends. What your code returns? What you except to return in case of error? Can you create a Object which rappresents a "no-valid-value"?

### Strings

For strings, as i said above, when you compare them if you can use literal.equals(variable) or try to put at the left side the least-probable-null (ok, i coined this term).

Example:

Suppose you have a `List` of `String` which will not contains `null` strings and you want to compare a string and check if it's inside this collection. You will not write `yourSearchString.equals(stringInsideCollection)` because `yourSearchString` is more probabile to be null, instead you are sure `stringInsideCollection` will **never** be null. So why make a `NullPointerException` if we can avoid it?

Another thing you can do with strings is never return `null`, instead **return an empty string** so you can do `return "";` (i know it look ugly) and in your caller code you can just do `if (returnedString.isEmpty())` so you merge together two conditions: You check if the server returned a valid response and if it's empty you don't want to do something.

### Collections

Not so much to say about it, `JDK` helped us with `Collections.emptyList` and others for all kind of collections types. Return it instead of `null` so you don't need to check null.

### Arrays

Like `Collections` you can return an empty array.

### Custom classes

It's a bit hard here, can you create a "default" status to your object?

An example of a "Default" status of a `Point` class would be a `Point` which always points to `[0, 0]`...

If you can, return it instead of null!

```
public class Point {
 public final int x;
 public final int y;

 public static final Point MAIN_POINT = new Point(0, 0);

 public Point(int x, int y) { this.x = x; this.y = y; }
}
```

so when you do an operation you could return `MAIN_POINT` instead of null.

Yeah, it looks great. But it could be a problem. What makes `[0, 0]` (example) a good thing to return instead of `null` or of point `[5, 3]`?

Sometimes instead of return null you could throw an exception! ... or leave null. Sometimes null is a great alternative to an exception (which costs).

To reduce your `null` checks we need more info about your `getAttrNo()` method. If it's something which shouldn't be null, when you set it check if it's null, if yes throw a `IllegalArgumentException`.

(*i like `null`*)

Comment: Corrected minor spelling mistake, otherwise awesome answer. +1.

Comment: I disagree with returning an empty list instead of null. This may lead to problems in your business logic if there is a case where an empty list is a valid output (or will be so in future). Therefore, if it is expected from a method to return some content but the method can't because of invalid arguments/state or anything else it should throw an exception instead and not return an "uncommon" value.

Comment: @valenterry Yes as i said don't exists a general way to avoid nulls sometimes you just need to accept them. Anyway there are cases where an empty list is ok, better than nuĺl. If a method is excepted to return some things means that you can avoid a null check in eromg cases, use .size directly and an else with "something went wrong"

Comment: @MarcoAcierno You don't need to accept them. You can either use Option Types (or similiar types, depending on the language) or - if `null` is not a valid return value as for example in databases - then you just throw exceptions. `null` should only be used for legacy compatibility or if the language is so poor that it does not provide any other mechanism.

Comment: @valenterry Java have Optional since v. 8 (or before with Lib) but personally i never see `null` as a problem it's normal that a pointer could be null and you can handle this case without problems. (but it's a my opinion, of course) maybe for others `null` could be see as a problem, especially when null could happen after a product is released and not handled correctly could do disasters, but it's something of "natural".

Answer (score 1):

- Remove `@SuppressWarnings` and remove the warnings by fixing your code.
- Don't use `System.out.println` for logging
- Don't catch unspecified `Exception`